# Error with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have a PC with Windows 8 4GB RAM 500GB HD and use Virtualbox 4.2.18 (current), however, already downloaded several types of isos of Ubuntu to virtualize and none of them got success. It takes forever to install and when it says that the machine needs to be rebooted to start using Ubuntu a message: virtualbox-O stopped working windows searching for a solution to this problem... and finally lose everything and does not install anything. Already downloaded several isos and also already tested in other versions of virtualbox and nothing's right. What can I do? What is the solution? Isos used: 12:04, 12:10, 13:04.

Comment: AAh English Bro,English!!

Answer (score 1):

1. try reinstalling virtual box
2. try using some prebuilt virtual box images from the internet
3. enable 3D acceleration, hardware-vt/amd-v, pae/nx, nested paging. Let your VM have atleast 2GB of ram for ubuntu. after installing ubuntu run the following commands : (otherwise ubuntu will be very slow)

   sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-guest-dkms virualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-utils